# Two functions with a given difference quotient composition (motivated by the MVT)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

We are looking for an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that there exist (at least) two functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and some functions $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$  with $\min\{x,y\}<h(x,y)<\max\{x,y\}$ (if $x\neq y$) and satisfying the functional equation $$g(h(x,y))= \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}, \;\;\; x\neq y.$$

**Note.** If $f$ is differentiable, $f'$ is invertible and $f'^{^{-1}}$ is continuous (e.g., if $f'$ is strictly increasing and continuous), then the mean value theorem (MVT) implies that $g=f'$ is a unique solution of the above functional equation (for some $h$ with the mentioned properties). Therefore, we should look for some examples in the following two cases:

Case 1) $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is not invertible (e.g., $f(t)=t^3$)

Case 1) $f$ is not differentiable at some points (e.g., $f(t)=|t|, sgn(t)$).

Our prefer is examples with  explicit formulas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because $h$ must be between the minimum and maximum of $x,y$.

Comment: Let $f=\operatorname{const}$ and $g$ be any function such that $g^{-1}(0)$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. For each distinct $x,y\in\Bbb R$ pick an arbitrary point $h(x,y)\in g^{-1}(0)\cap (\min\{x,y\},\max\{x,y\}) $. Then $g(h(x,y))=0=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}.$

Comment: Thanks. Any other  non-constant examples?

Comment: Similarly we can show that if $f(x)=x$ then we can pick any function $g$ such that $g^{-1}(1)$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. Also for any $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that  $g^{-1}(t)$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ for each $t\in\Bbb R$, for  each distinct $x,y\in\Bbb R$ 
we can pick an arbitrary point $h(x,y)\in g^{-1}\left(\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right)\cap (\min\{x,y\},\max\{x,y\}) $. So I guess in order to obtain a more constructive answer we need to impose some restrictions on $g$, for instance, that it is continuous.

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky - Good idea, thanks again.